# phonegap android  console log not working

Tags: javascript, iphone, android, html, cordova

The console log like console.log("Test Text"); is not working android emulator.
But it works in iphone semulator.
I am using phonegap with html/css/javascript and want to show my debuging information.

Is there any other way to display console in android.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have to show the LogCat tab in Eclipse. There, Web Console messages (including JS errors) will show up. It's a little verbose so you have to filter to show just the Web Console tags but it works well. Described here: [Showing console console.log output and Javascript errors with Phonegap on Android/Eclipse](http://www.frenchguys.com/wordpress/showing-console-consolelog-output-phonegap-androideclipse/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [weinre](https://github.com/apache/incubator-cordova-weinre) to show the console.log output in a desktop browser.

Comment: weinre is for web browser, but we are developing web app to Native app using phonegaop.So Element Inspector would not help us.

Comment: weinre includes a console in addition to the inspector. Of course as Toni says, logcat also shows console output for the emulator and most Android devices. Note that logcat does not include console output on HTC devices